# How to make the program choose a random string from a list and not use it again throughout the entire program in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, random

I am making a program that will need to print a lot of hints and in order to avoid repetition and make it more interesting, I want the program to pick those hints randomly from lists that I am going to make. I also want to remove a hint after being used so the program doesn't use it again in a place that it won't need to. Can someone show an example of that on this code:

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print(random.choice(foo))
```

Comment: Shuffle the list, and `pop` values from it…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.shuffle` and `foo.pop`:

```
>>> import random
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> random.shuffle(foo)
>>> print(foo.pop())
d
>>> print(foo.pop())
e
>>> print(foo.pop())
a
>>> foo
['c', 'b']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `pop` method:

```
import random

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
i = random.randint(0, len(foo));
bar= foo.pop(i);

print(bar);
print(foo);
```

Check more in Python Documentation about Data Structures: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html